# If $\sum_{n}A_n$ is convergent, then $\sum_{n} (-1)^{n} A_n$ is also convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If you know that the series $\sum_{n}A_n$ is convergent, i have to prove or give a counterexample of the following statement:

The series $\sum_{n} (-1)^{n} A_n$ is also convergent.

Please help with this one.

Comment: The answers below are good. An additional thing to think about: If $A_n$ is monotone and converges to 0, then is $\sum (-1)^n A_n$ convergent?

Answer (score 8):

Take $$a_n=(-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$$ It is known that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}=-\log(2),$$ but $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$$ diverges. If you have $A_n\geq 0$ for nearly all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ you have the absolute konvergence and then the statement is true

Comment: Thank you, but how do you know that the second sum is - log 2?

Comment: it's from the taylor series of the logarithm, if you just need the convergence take leibniz test

Answer (score 4):

It's false, take $$A_n = (-1)^n\frac{1}{n}$$. But if $A_n \geq 0$ for all $n$ then it's true by the [Leibniz's condition](http://planetmath.org/AlternatingSeriesTest.html)
 for alternating series.

Comment: If $A_n \ge 0$, it is true, but *not* by Leibniz's test. (The sequence $A_n$ doesn't have to be decreasing.) It is true by absolute convergence, though.

Comment: Yes you are right.